# VBA Email with pasted chart and text in body

Tags: vba, email, excel, outlook

The goal of the following code is to paste the selected chart into the email body *below* my text. However, it continues to paste it above my text. How can I change it to make it paste below? Thanks!

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail
    .CC = "xyz@anc.com"
    .BCC = "abc@xyz.com"
    .Subject = "Test"
    .Body = "Dear" & "Macro "

    ActiveSheet.Range("P36:X46").Copy
    Set wEditor = OutApp.ActiveInspector.WordEditor

    wEditor.Application.Selection.Paste

.display
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the selection start and end. Adding an extra line break might also be a good idea. You should also use MailItem.GetInspector instead of Application.ActiveInspector since the message is not yet displayed.

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail
    .CC = "xyz@anc.com"
    .BCC = "abc@xyz.com"
    .Subject = "Test"
    .Body = "Dear" & "Macro " & vbCrLf

    ActiveSheet.Range("P36:X46").Copy
    set vInspector = OutMail.GetInspector
    Set wEditor = vInspector.WordEditor

    wEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
    wEditor.Application.Selection.End = wEditor.Application.Selection.Start

    wEditor.Application.Selection.Paste

.display
```

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry Streblechenko !
Would there also be a way to insert it in the middle of the email body? Say I included 4 or five spaces after "Macro" and then wrote more text. But I wanted the chart pasted in between "Macro" and the end.

Comment: Sure, just calculate the offset correctly. the script above uses the length of the message body, you need some other position. E.g. if you want to insert in front of a string "Some text" in the message body, you need to use StrPost() to calculate the position and set the selection start appropriately.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I'm using it like this wEditor.Application.Selection.Start = STRPOST(.Body, "Any")
But I keep getting sub or function not defined.

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out using Instr. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Great Method to Put Chart in between the HTML body of the mail